# IBM BlueMix - Provisioning a BigInsights 4 cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-cloud, provisioning, biginsights

I am new to BlueMix and got registered yesterday. I am trying to follow the manual here (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/BigInsights/index-gentopic1.html#provisioncluster) to provision a new cluster. Step 2 reads "From the IBM Bluemix catalog, add the BigInsights service, leaving it unbound under App".
However, under Catalog I can't seem to find any BigInsights service. There is a "Data and Analytics" section. However, there doesn't seem to be any BigInsights service there. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the service is available in the [catalog of the US region](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/) and is labeled "[BigInsights for Apache Hadoop](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/biginsights-for-apache-hadoop/)".

Comment: Thanks - that helped!